# Remove class with jQuery according to user behavior

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" class="comment">
```

that already adds a class of '.error' when a certain dropdown option is selected:

```
.error {    
  color:red;
}
```

But I am now trying to remove the '.error' class when the user begins to type in the textbox, something like:

```
if ($('.comment').val().length > 0) {
  removeClass('.error');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from some minor syntax errors, the main question is *when* you want that code to be called.  To check on every keystroke, use `keyup()`. And if you check the `value` and `removeClass()` on `this` (where that's the specific element the key was typed in), you can have multiple `.comment` fields with the same behavior.

```js
$('.comment').keyup(
  function() {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
      $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
  }
)
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;   // changed for easier demo visibility
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" class="comment error">
<input type="text" name="txt2" id="txt2" class="comment error">
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.comment').removeClass('error');
```